# How can I redirect user to another page after login - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the project I'm working on, it's common to pass links to details of a purchase on email, but when the user opens the link it asks for authentication in the system, but after logging in, it is redirected to the home page (the system panel) and not for the purchase details.

```
if (admin) {
 that.router.navigate(['/main-panel'], { replaceUrl: true });
} else (seller) {
 that.router.navigate(['/main-panel-seller'], { replaceUrl: true });
}
```

The only validation I do is where I'm going to send this user, there is any way to check the previous url? Or somewhere where I can find this url information is stored.

Comment: You can add a Id as QueryParam on the link, then use an Angular Guard on the home page route, check inside the angular guard with the router for the queryParam id an redirect to specific route you want there.

Answer (score 3):

When you redirect the user to the login page you can pass the original url as params , and navigate to it when he's logged in

For example :
in the auth gard

```
this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
```

and in the controller :

```
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/'; 
his.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
```

([Source](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard))